# Split view of a CSV in Bash

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to view large CSV files in a terminal (not huge; simply more than can be displayed in the terminal window at once).

The best solution I've currently got is this:

```
column -s, -t -n < data.csv | less -S
```

It works well, but I'd really like to be able to split the window, so the header row of the csv will always be visible (and stay aligned with horizontal scrolling).

Comment: I can almost imagine doing this in vi - I can't get it to open with the correct split, and haven't found a "`horizontal scrollbind`" to work with `:set nowrap`.

Comment: How about vim's split? And is LibreOffice an option?

Comment: @ott: vim's split would be perfect, except for the horizontal scrollbind in my above comment. Also, I couldn't figure out if it's possible to open it pre-split from the command-line

Comment: @ott: LibreOffice is what I currently use, but it's a lot of heavy lifting for a quick browse around a csv.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal.app on OS X allows you to split the window and scroll both parts individually. This doesn't work well with apps that scroll themselves though, like `less`.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>CSV sample data taken from [here](http://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is now way of doing this in bash. Why don't you just open two terminals, align them and open the file in each. That way you would see the header in one and be able to scroll in another.

I highly recommend [`terminator`](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html) a very powerful terminator emulator with the ability to split panes. What you want to do would really be easy there, just split a window horizontally and open the document in both resulting shells.

Comment: Ideally this is quick way to open and look at a csv. If it's going to take any thinking, I might as well just open it OpenOffice.

Comment: Not much thinking @AndrewWood , if you are running terminator it would consist of `column -s, -t -n < data.csv | less -S` then Ctrl+E to split the teminal, Up and enter to run the last command. Quite quick really.

Comment: I'll see if I can convince my sysadmin to install terminator ;)

Comment: This has the same problem as I was having with vim. When I scroll horizontally, the column headers go out of alignment.